# How to use Common Table Expression with parameters?

Tags: t-sql

I have a stored procedure with 2 CTEs. The second CTE has a parameter

```
WITH path_sequences
AS
(

),
WITH categories
AS
(
    ... WHERE CategoryId = @CategoryId 
    // I dont know how to get this initial parameter inside the CTE 
)

SELECT * FROM path_sequences p
JOIN categories c
ON p.CategoryId = c.CategoryId
```

The initial parameter that I need to get inside the second TCE is **p.CategoryId**. How do I do that without having to create another stored procedure to contain the second CTE?

Thanks for helping

Comment: It would be nice to add to the title which database system you are asking about.This means that you might get answers that are not relevant to your usecase.
Of course people might be able to figure it out by looking at the SQL samples, but this is not always the case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create table valued function

```
create function ftCategories
(
    @CategoryID int
)
returns table
as return
    with categories as (
        ... WHERE CategoryId = @CategoryId 
    )
    select Col1, Col2 ...
    from categories
```

and use it as

```
SELECT *
FROM path_sequences p
    cross apply ftCategories(p.CategoryId) c
```

Comment: Best to not call tables or views within functions

Comment: Could someone explain @TamusJRoyce's comment? What does it mean to "call tables or views within functions" and why is it best not to do that?

Comment: @MaxChernyak inlining functions cannot happen when tables or views are accessed within functions. It causes a naive linear lookup. Which increases joins by O(n), which is very expensive. Table indexes are not optimally utilized either. If the tables and what is being joined to are small, this doesn't matter. But it can hamper performance as data scales.

Comment: @MaxChernyak you see where `select Col1, Col2 ... from categories` is in this example function? categories is a view or table, since it is in the from clause. If it was @categories, it would be a value table. Which also suffers from issues? I'm not sure with 150+ sql server 2022 engine though. That may not be a concern anymore. Anyone, please let us know if table values still cause performance issues or not here

Answer (score 16):

I have created simple query using your code. You can use it like -

```sql
DECLARE @CategoryId INT
SET @CategoryId = 1

;WITH path_sequences
AS
(
SELECT 1 CategoryId
),
categories
AS
(
    SELECT 1 CategoryId WHERE 1 = @CategoryId
)

SELECT * FROM path_sequences p
JOIN categories c
ON p.CategoryId = c.CategoryId
```

Answer (score 8):

This syntax is for External Aliases:

```
  -- CTES With External Aliases:
    WITH Sales_CTE (SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, SalesYear)
    AS
    -- Define the CTE query.
    (
        SELECT SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS SalesYear
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
        WHERE SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL
    )
```

The only way to add parameters is to use scope variables like so:

```
--Declare a variable:
DECLARE @category INT

WITH 
MyCTE1 (exName1, exName2)
AS
(
    SELECT <SELECT LIST>
    FROM <TABLE LIST>
    --Use the variable as 'a parameter'
    WHERE CategoryId = @CategoryId
)
```

Answer (score 6):

First remove the second WITH, separate each cte with just a comma. Next you can add parameters like this:

```
DECLARE @category INT; -- <~~ Parameter outside of CTEs

WITH 
MyCTE1 (col1, col2)  -- <~~ were poorly named param1 and param2 previously
AS
(
    SELECT blah blah
    FROM blah
    WHERE CategoryId = @CategoryId
),
MyCTE2 (col1, col2)  -- <~~ were poorly named param1 and param2 previously
AS
(

)
SELECT *
FROM MyCTE2 
INNER JOIN MyCTE1 ON ...etc....
```

EDIT (and CLARIFICATION):

I have renamed the columns from param1 and param2 to col1 and col2 (which is what I meant originally).

My example assumes that each SELECT has exactly two columns. The columns are optional if you want to return all of the columns from the underlying query AND those names are unique. If you have more or less columns than what is being SELECTed you will need to specify names.

Here is another example:

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    FirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ManagerId INT NULL
)
```

**Fill table with some rows:**

```
INSERT INTO Employee 
(FirstName, LastName, ManagerId)
VALUES
('Donald', 'Duck', 5)

INSERT INTO Employee 
(FirstName, LastName, ManagerId)
VALUES
('Micky', 'Mouse', 5)

INSERT INTO Employee 
(FirstName, LastName, ManagerId)
VALUES
('Daisy', 'Duck', 5)

INSERT INTO Employee 
(FirstName, LastName, ManagerId)
VALUES
('Fred', 'Flintstone', 5)

INSERT INTO Employee 
(FirstName, LastName, ManagerId)
VALUES
('Darth', 'Vader', null)

INSERT INTO Employee 
(FirstName, LastName, ManagerId)
VALUES
('Bugs', 'Bunny', null)

INSERT INTO Employee 
(FirstName, LastName, ManagerId)
VALUES
('Daffy', 'Duck', null)
```

**CTEs:**

```
DECLARE @ManagerId INT = 5;

WITH 
MyCTE1 (col1, col2, col3, col4)
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Employee e 
    WHERE 1=1
    AND e.Id = @ManagerId
 ),
 MyCTE2 (colx, coly, colz, cola)
 AS
 (
    SELECT e.*
    FROM Employee e 
    INNER JOIN MyCTE1 mgr ON mgr.col1 = e.ManagerId
    WHERE 1=1
 )
 SELECT 
   empsWithMgrs.colx,
   empsWithMgrs.coly,
   empsWithMgrs.colz,
   empsWithMgrs.cola      
 FROM MyCTE2 empsWithMgrs
```

Notice in the CTEs the columns are being aliased. MyCTE1 exposes columns as col1, col2, col3, col4 and MyCTE2 references MyCTE1.col1 when it references it. Notice the final select uses MyCTE2's column names.

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: @marcellomiorelli this does not work, see: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972(v=sql.105).aspx
to understand what the `(param1, param2)` part does

Comment: I was meaning @category as the parameter and used a bad naming choice (param1 and param2) for the column names. I should have named them col2 and col2 (or similar).

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still struggling with this, the only thing you need to is terminate your declaration of variables with a semicolon before the CTE. Nothing else is required.

```
DECLARE @test AS INT = 42;
WITH x 
     AS (SELECT @test AS 'Column') 

SELECT * 
FROM   x
```

Results:

```
Column
-----------
42

(1 row affected)
```